# Remove sections of a string or parse data?

Tags: python-3.4

I have a long string of data and I'm trying to pick out one small piece of it. The position in the string changes all the time. A sample of the data is below. I have researched `strip` and `parse`, but I'm thinking `strip` is the wrong choice, but `parse` might do it.

`Data: {'DriverCarSLFirstRPM': 6000.0, 'DriverCarFuelMaxLtr': 44.987, 'DriverCarMaxFuelPct': 0.3, 'Drivers': [{'CarIsAI': 0, 'LicSubLevel': 1, 'TeamID': 0}`

I'm trying to get the value for `DriverCarFuelMaxLtr`. Should I be trying to strip the data before and after that value, or is there a way to seperate the file at the commas and then read the values?

Comment: I've been trying to use lstrip and rstrip to get it down just to the data I need - which is not working and same for parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON was invalid to start with.

This has now been validated:

```
{
    "DriverCarSLFirstRPM": 6000.0,
    "DriverCarFuelMaxLtr": 44.987,
    "DriverCarMaxFuelPct": 0.3,
    "Drivers": [{
        "CarIsAI": 0,
        "LicSubLevel": 1,
        "TeamID": 0
    }]
}
```

This should help you get started:

```
import json

data = '{"DriverCarSLFirstRPM": 6000.0, "DriverCarFuelMaxLtr": 44.987,"DriverCarMaxFuelPct": 0.3,"Drivers": [{"CarIsAI": 0,"LicSubLevel": 1,"TeamID": 0}]}'
info = json.loads(data)
# To get the value of "DriverCarFuelMaxLtr"
print(info.get('DriverCarFuelMaxLtr'))
```

**Output:** `44.987`

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. The string was a subset of a much larger string, which I cut down for posting. Thanks for pointing out that I missed adding back the bracket. I'll dig into this further but this seems very reasonable. I have no previous experience with json - looks like I have another direction to go in my reading. Thank you again!

Comment: @NickGreen Glad I could help. Would you mind accepting my answer?

Comment: Only trouble I've found so far with this solution is that my data is provided from a tertiary program, and it's all in single ' not ", so it's throwing an error for me. Any quick work arounds?

Comment: @NickGreen There's a few workarounds. What I would do is setup another question asking that and I'm sure someone will provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a stringified json object. You could [look into](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) Json.loads().
Or if I am mistaken and for some reason you can not transform it into a dictionary I would just use regex (regular expressions).
If you don't know about regex you can look at [this guide](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and learn [how to use them](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm) in python.

Comment: This is not an answer. You could've simply added this as a comment.

Comment: Oh, ok! should I move it? also, I am not sure when to use answers or comments.

Comment: yeah, either move and delete, or make a more complete answer.   See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer - like provide an example, test your proposed solution on the input, show an example regex, ...